# How to perform search and sort on dynamically populate DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table that has it`s rows dynamically generated based on database data. My initial table looks like this:

```
<table id="tabela-campistas" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>N&#186; Ficha</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>Camiseta</th>
        <th>Especial</th>
       <th>Check In</th>
       <th>Tribo</th>
       <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="campistas-table-body">
       </tbody>
</table>
```

I initialize the table like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      // datatable
    $('#tabela-campistas').DataTable({
      language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Buscar ..."
      },
      "paging": false,
      "info": false,
      "columns": [
      { responsivePriority: 1 },
      { responsivePriority: 2 },
      { responsivePriority: 5 },
      { responsivePriority: 6 },
      { responsivePriority: 8 },
      { responsivePriority: 7 },
      { responsivePriority: 4 },
      { responsivePriority: 3 },
      { "orderable": false,
        responsivePriority: 9
      }
    ],
    responsive: true
    });
});
```

Once the user is signed in I populate the table with database data:

```
var campistasRef = firebase.database().ref('fac-2/campistas/');
campistasRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
   populateTable(data);
 });

function populateTable(data){
  var veganIcon = '<td><p>especial-nao</p><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
  var checkInIcon = '<td><p>nao-checkin</p><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';

  if (data.val().vegan) {
    veganIcon = '<td><p>especial-sim</p><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
  }

  if (data.val().checkin) {
    checkInIcon = '<td><p>sim-checkin</p><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
  }

  var triboIcon = '<td><p>sem-tribo</p><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  var tribo = data.val().team;
  var color = 'style="color: green"';

  if (tribo != 'NENHUM') {
    if (tribo === 'amarela') {
      color = 'style="color: yellow"';
    } else if (tribo === 'azul') {
      color = 'style="color: blue"';
    } else if (tribo === 'verde') {
      color = 'style="color: green"';
    } else if (tribo === 'vermelha') {
      color = 'style="color: red"';
    } else if (tribo === 'laranja') {
      color = 'style="color: rgb(255, 140, 0)"';
    } else if (tribo === 'marrom') {
      color = 'style="color: brown"';
    } else if (tribo === 'preta') {
      color = 'style="color: black"';
    } else {
      color = 'style="color: purple"';
    }

    triboIcon = '<td><p>sem-tribo</p><i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"'+color+'></i>';

  }

  $("#campistas-table-body").append('<tr><td>'+data.val().number+'</td><td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">'+data.val().username+'</td><td>'+data.val().email+'</td><td>'+data.val().phone+'</td><td>'+data.val().size.toUpperCase()+'</td><'+veganIcon+checkInIcon+triboIcon+'</td><td class="edit-td"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>');
}
```

The problem here is, the page first load and there is only row in the table saying "No data available in table", after a few second the rows load form DB into the table, however that first row saying "No data available in table" never disappeared. And what really brings me here, all searches and sorting came out empty like there is no data there even tough the data is being displayed if you inspect the html the table rows are actually there. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of append try using .html() @AlexanderKrabbe

Comment: Thanks for the reply @parth. If I just replace append to .html() it works but I only get one row, how can I use .html() to achieve the append result?

Comment: If You wants to append new rows to existing data, use .append() because .html() will replace all existing data. You can check if datatable has one row and its text is 'No data available' then use .html() else use .append() @AlexandreKrabbe

Comment: I just tried that, it successfully populates the table just like the append method did. However DataTable doesn't`t seem to count it as data since when I try to search or Sort it the table goes empty with only one row saying "No data available in table". @parth

Comment: I think when you are populating data through ajax, it wont get the new data that has been added, so you should create entire table all time, instead of just table body.@AlexandreKrabbe

Comment: That solved it, thanks! If you can post the answer so I can chose as the right answer, otherwise I`ll have to wait until I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You add data through ajax in datatable, jQuery plugin datatable wont get the data so you will have to load entire table instead of just table-body.